# Combining columns from different files into a single column in a new file in R

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have extracted chosen columns from multiple files into new as many data sets as files. Now I need to rbind all of them into a single column in a new file.

I am using below command

```
comments <- bind_rows(data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7)
```

Each of the data set has a single column but colname is different and I want all of them in a single column in comments data set.

The output I get is comments dataset with 7 columns instead of 1, struggling to understand why. Pls help

Comment: Try `bind_rows(lapply(mget(paste0("data", 1:7)), setNames, "Col1"))`

Comment: Thanks worked with a warning                                                                      {In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character}. Could you also pls explain what was wrong earlier

Comment: I tried on some example data and didn't show any warning with dplyr_0.5.0

Comment: If you have factor column, then the warning is expected as the levels would be different.  It is better to have character class, but I think this should still work

Comment: Thanks. So I guess different colnames the problem here

Comment: It is not related to the column names, it is the values in the columns

Comment: FOr example `bind_rows(data.frame(v1=factor("a")), data.frame(v1=factor("b")))` also gives the warning.  It is a friendly warning

Comment: no I meant why a simple bind_rows was not combining all into 1 single column

Comment: I think it is a feature of bind_rows to check the column names and if different create new columns,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the column names all at once in a `list` and then apply `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(mget(paste0("data", 1:7)), setNames, "Col1") %>% 
                     bind_rows()
```

---

Or use `rbindlist` from `data.table` which will give a single column

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(paste0("data", 1:7))
```